# Ruby: How to split text into lines?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have a text in variable say

`Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old`

How can I put the last line on next line?

`Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. 
It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old`

Comment: Do you mean specifically this last text or any last sentence?

Comment: What do you mean by "last line"? If you already have them as lines, then they are already in different lines.

Comment: `text.gsub(/\. /, ".\n")`

Comment: you can add a line break with `\n` in a double quoted string, so `puts "random text.\nIt has roots..."` If you want to break at character type and line length or something, that's a bit more complicated.

Comment: "How can i put the last line on next line?" – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* ask a focused, narrow question on [so] with a [mcve], a precise description of your problem, all error messages, a full specification of what you want, and examples.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show last line of your paragraph to be display in next line you can use `\n`.
like

```
"Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. \nIt has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `rpartition` to get the last sentence separated.

```
string = "Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old"

start, middle, finish = string.rpartition('. ')

answer = middle == '. ' ? [start, finish].join(".\n") : finish

puts answer
=> Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.
It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old
```

The reason for the ternary is to handle the case that no sentence break (". ") is found, in which case the entire string will be in the `finish` variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to work with any arbitrary number of paragraphs just creating a new line for the last one you can use:

```
to_fix_1 = "Somewhere above. The cityscape. Gerwefegrrfqegrwb.".split('.')
to_fix_2 = "Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old".split('.')

converter = lambda { |splitted, res| splitted.each_with_index { |p,i| (i+1) == splitted.length && splitted.length != 1 ? (res += "\n"+p.strip+'.') : (res += p+'.') } and return res }

result = converter.call(to_fix_1, '')
puts result

=> Somewhere above. The cityscape.
Gerwefegrrfqegrwb.

result = converter.call(to_fix_2, '')
puts result

=> Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.
It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.
```

(I just had fun writing it, don't judge)

Answer (score 0):

You may substitute a period + line break (.\n) for the period (.) with the `gsub` method as follows:

```
text = "Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old"

text_w_break = text.gsub(/\. /, ".\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of doing this, but the question is unclear.

If you were to split every sentence into new lines, you could do something like:

```
string.split(".").join(".\n")
```

If you were to only extract the last sentence you could also do something like.

```
sentences = string.split(".")
*all_but_last, last = sentences
result = all_but_last.join(".") + "\n" + last
```